# OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder().getDocumentElement() creates empty elements for elements witout a body

Tags: xml, axiom, woodstox

When I pass the string `"<a></a>"`, `OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder().getDocumentElement()` creates OMElement of `<a/>`. what I need is OMElement of `<a></a>`. Is there a configuration for this? Tried `StAXParserConfiguration` but no configurations were found.

Answer (score -1):

`<a></a>` and `<a/>` are two strictly equivalent representations of an empty element with name `a`. Axiom (just like DOM and most other XML APIs for that matter) doesn't store the details of how that empty element was represented in the input document, so given `<a></a>` as input, it may produce `<a/>` as output.